# convert array([[ number ]]) to 'number'

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.7

I have this line of codes in `python`:

```
Rad[i] = {'j': JY[:, :, 0], 'h': JY[:, :, 0] + 1j * JY[:, :,2]}
```

with the output of `Rad[i]`  as:

> ```
> {'j': array([[0.04816103]]), 'h': array([[0.04816103-5.16810074j]])}
> ```

so, I want to have output as :

> ```
> {'j': '0.04816103', 'h': '0.04816103-5.16810074j'}
> ```

How could I do that?

thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used as this instruction, make two parameters referee one to another as below:

```
Rad[i] = {'j': str(JY[:, :, 0][0][0]), 'h': str(JY[:, :, 0][0][0] + 1j * JY[:, :,2][0][0])}
```

Output is:

```
{'j': '0.04816103', 'h': '(5.21626177-5.11993971j)'}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [24]: x=np.array([[0.04816103]])                                                                          
In [25]: x                                                                                                   
Out[25]: array([[0.04816103]])
In [26]: x.shape                                                                                             
Out[26]: (1, 1)
In [27]: x[0,0]                                                                                              
Out[27]: 0.04816103
In [28]: x[0][0]                                                                                             
Out[28]: 0.04816103
In [29]: x.squeeze()                                                                                         
Out[29]: array(0.04816103)
In [30]: _.shape                                                                                             
Out[30]: ()
In [34]: x.item()                                                                                            
Out[34]: 0.04816103
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are dealing with a 1-element array, you can extract the value of it using

```
JY[:,:,0].item()
```

anywhere you are working with an array (i.e. JY[:,:,0], JY[:,:,2]), just add .item() and the output will be what you want